# Make an equation from expression "1 4 9 100"

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers, physics

Fill the gaps of the expression $1$ $4$  $9$  $100$  with mathematical operations $+,-,*,/$, physical units and an $=$ sign, such that a correct equation is created.
Example: expression $1$  $100$  $100$  $9$  -> $1 \text{m} = 100 \text{mm} + 100  \cdot  9 \text{mm}$

Comment: Would something like ``1 feet =  2 * 2 * 3 inches`` for 1 2 2 3 be allowed?

Comment: yes, this is a valid solution for 1 2 2 3

Comment: what about something like `4 ft * 6 in = 2 ft^2 * 1` for 4 6 2 1? where ft^2 is the same as sqft which is square feet?

Comment: @rhavelka, yes, this is a valid solution as well.

Comment: Also is the approximate symbol work? Say like 36 cm ≈ 1 ft

Comment: @IsaacRoanSison I do not think that the approximate symbol would work since the question strictly states an "=" sign.

Comment: Are square root symbols allowed? `1^4 + 9 = sqrt(100)`. Also `1^4^9 m = 100 cm`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hmm, let's see.

> 1 hour = 4 * 9 * 100 seconds

Answer (score 9):

A few more possibilities:

> With pints and fluid ounces
>  
>  1x4 pt = 9 pt - 100 fl oz

> With feet and inches
>  
>  1 ft - 4 in = 9 ft - 100 in

> With angles
>  
>  1° = 4x9x100"

Answer (score 7):

> There are some non-standard "journalism units" like "Olympic swimming pool" for volume, "Texas" for area, or "Library of Congress" for amount of data. One of these, recognized by the [units](https://www.gnu.org/software/units/) program, is "football field = 100 yards".
>  If we allow these, then **1 football field = 4 * 9 inches * 100**

> Alternatively, if you permit SI prefixes on very non-SI units, then **1 * 4 * 9 inches = 100 centiyards** :)

Answer (score 4):

> if base number is a valid unit then  1 * 4 * 9 (decimal)= 100 (Senary, heximal, or seximal, base-6)